# Creating a child task, linking it to a parent and changing the assignment via API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I need to use PowerShell to make a call to Azure DevOps that needs to do the following -
- Create Tasks
- Link Tasks to Parent Feature
- Change who the tasks are assigned to

I am able to create the tasks and link to a parent feature (123456) but the assigned to part is not working.

```
$tasks = @("Task 1","Task 2","Task 3")

foreach ($task in $tasks)
{
    $body = @"
    [
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "$task"
        },
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
            "url": "https://blahblah.com/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/wit/workItems/123456"
        }
    }
    ]
"@
```

I tried adding the 'add' op with '"/fields/System.AssignedTo"'. It assigns the tasks properly, but then the linking to the parent feature isn't working - so the tasks end up not linked at all.

Actual Code Tried ::

```
$tasks = @("Task 1","Task 2","Task 3")

foreach ($task in $tasks)
{
    $body = @"
    [
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "$task"
        },
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
            "url": "https://blahblah.com/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/wit/workItems/123456"
                 },
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
        "value": "My_Display_Name"
        }
    ]
"@
```

Comment: Can you share you exact code you tried?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes, updated OP.

Comment: Hi, did you have been got the solution now? I notice that only little changed on your script shared below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tasks = @("Task 1","Task 2","Task 3")

foreach ($task in $tasks)
{
    $body = @"
    [
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "$task"
        },
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/relations/-",
        "value": {
            "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
            "url": "https://blahblah.com/DefaultCollection/myproject/_apis/wit/workItems/123456"
                 },
        },
        {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
        "value": "My_Display_Name"
        }
    ]
"@
```